# Jbpm human task automation or bulk action

Tags: jbpm, redhat-bpm

I have a requirement where in our processes create a human task for the support team to re-trigger failed process. They do it by passing a parameter "Y" after claiming the task and submitting it.

My need is to automate this in a way any tasks that are created to be claimed automatically and submit by passing the "Y" parameter. Or do this as a bulk where in I select say 20 human tasks and re-trigger them by a single action.
Any ideas. Am totally in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating human tasks, create signal processes. From the business central we can send bulk signal to multiple processes, that way you can re-trigger bulk failed process.